# How to get the value of json object in jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following json:

```
{
    "Validation": {
    "status": "Validation:INITIATED",
    "subStatus": "Close:COMPLETED"
    },
    "Analysis": {
    "status": "Analysis:COMPLETED",
    "subStatus": "Close:COMPLETED"
    },
    "decomposition": {
    "status": "Decomposition:Inprogress",
    "subStatus": ""
    }
}
```

I need to get value of status and subStatus from the json.
I have already tried the following:

```
$.each(dataStatus, function(key,value) {
    $.each(value,function(k,val){
       alert(val)
    })
});
```

But i don't get the desired output.
Please suggest

Comment: Did you try `dataStatus.Validation.status` & `dataStatus.Validation.subStatus` ?

Comment: Yes, but i need the value dynamically like status of validation , status of analysis etc

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hdp9x0cq/ delivers the expected output. You might have to use json decode before, if you got this json as a string.

Comment: Yes, value is coming but i can differentiate the status value or substatus value?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "dynamically" ?
You can access all the nodes and subnodes or just access a subStatus for exemple based on a variable ?
For exemple :

```
dataStatus['Validation'].status
```

would return you the status of 'Validation'.
You can have a variable instead of 'Validation', but it must be a string.

```
var myRecordName = 'Validation';
alert(dataStatus[myRecordName].status);
```

You can do the same for 'status' and 'substatus' of course...